# Nested sc.variables in Unicorn configuration

Tags: configuration, unicorn

I have some Unicorn configuration files which use a specific $variable for the physicalRootPath:

```
physicalRootPath="$(sourceFolder)\foundation\Serialization\Serialization"
```

Now I would like to have the $sourceFolder variable be dependent of the Sitecore standard $dataFolder variable. So I have defined:

```
<sc.variable name="sourceFolderPublic" value="$(dataFolder)\Serialization" />
```

But when I run /unicorn.aspx I get the following error:
[image]
It seems the $(dataFolder) variable is not filled in?

I've narrowed it down even further. In the root Sitecore.config I have directly defined the following config and it works:
[image: working config]
But when I use this it doesn't work (crash)
[image: not working config]
This is the stacktrace
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping you already solved this, but I think I see the problem:

```
physicalRootPath="$(sourceFolder)\foundation\Serialization\Serialization"
```

This is your configuration for the `physicalRootPath` - note that your variable is called `sourceFolder`

This is your definition for your variable:

```
<sc.variable name="sourceFolderPublic" value="$(dataFolder)\Serialization" />
```

Note that you have called that `sourceFolderPublic` - make these 2 variables match and it should work ok.

Answer (score 0):

I performed something similar to what you're trying to achieve and it worked fine.  The "datafolder" variable was replaced accordingly.  Can you check your `ShowConfig.aspx` and see if it's being applied.  You should see the updated targetDataStore's physicalRoot.  If you still see the "dataFolder" variable, then it's likely not finding it.

Comment: Hi Marco. Thank you for looking at this! I seem to be having a problem with the order in which the variables are resolved. If I don't use $(sourceFolderPublic) in my Unicorn files I do see it resolves fine in Showconfig.aspx. It seems unicorn uses the configuration before it is completed?

Comment: @Gluip, you can either ensure this file is patched later by placing it in a folder that's name starts with "z" or use patch:after attributes to do the same thing.  Or you could make sure the config that sets the datafolder variable is set earlier.